# Django Admin: Setting list_display conditionally

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there any admin model method like get_list_display() or some way that I can have some conditions to set different list_display values?

```
class FooAdmin (model.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def get_list_display ():
        if some_cond:
            return ('field', 'tuple',)
        return ('other', 'field', 'tuple',)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ModelAdmin` class has a method called `get_list_display` which takes request as a parameter, by default returning the `list_display` property of the class.

So you can do for example:

```
class ShowEFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    """ A dummy filter which just adds a filter option to show the E column,
        but doesn't modify the queryset.
    """
    title = _("Show E column")
    parameter_name = "show_e"

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [
            ("yes", "Yes"),
        ]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset

class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e"
    )
    list_filter = (
        ShowEFilter,
    )


    def get_list_display(self, request):
        """ Removes the E column unless "Yes" has been selected in the 
            dummy filter.
        """
        list_display = list(self.list_display)
        if request.GET.get("show_e", "no") != "yes":
            list_display.remove("e")

        return list_display
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making that a property?

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @property
    def list_display(self):
        if some_cond:
            return ('field','tuple')
        return ('other','field','tuple')
```

I haven't but it may work.

I'm also fairly certain you could spell it:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    if CONDITION:
        list_display = ('field','tuple')
    else:
        list_display = ('other','field','tuple')
```

But this one would only run the check at the time the FooAdmin class is interpreted: but if you were basing the test on settings.SOME_VALUE, for instance, then it may work.

Note also that the `self` in the first example is the instance of the FooAdmin class, not Foo itself.

Answer (score 0):

You want to override the changelist_view method of the admin.ModelAdmin class:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
  # just in case you are having problems with carry over from previous
  # iterations of the view, always SET the self.list_display instead of adding
  # to it

  if something:
    self.list_display = ['action_checkbox'] + ['dynamic_field_1']
  else:
    self.list_display = ['action_checkbox'] + ['dynamic_field_2']

  return super(MyModelAdminClass, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

The 'action_checkbox' is what django uses to know to display the checkbox on the left hand side for the action drop down, so make sure you include it in setting the self.list_display. As usual if you simply set list_display for the ModelAdmin class normally you don't need to include it.